# When using a template in c++, I had a duplicate error

Tags: c++

When using a template in c++, creating the same cpp file as the header resolves the link error.
But I had a duplicate error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that illustrates your problem clearly. In particular, show a simple code sample and copy the error **text** *verbatim*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

For template, there is a way to make cpp file the same as header and not include header in cpp. Another way is to implement all of them in a header file without a cpp file. No matter which method you use.

Comment: This answer is as clear as the question...